# Global structure pointer initialization

Tags: c, struct, initialization, global

### Structure definition

```
struct list
{
  struct list **next, **prev;
}
```

### core.c

```
//Global struct
struct list *threads = {&threads, &threads};  //Warnings here:

// warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
// warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
// warning: (near initialization for 'threads')
```

PS: I don't have a `main` function in this file. And this has to be global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the *pointer-to-struct-list* variable `threads` with a pointer to a `struct list`. `{&threads, &threads}` is not a pointer to a `struct list`, but it could be a `struct list`.

In order to define an actual structure instance and obtain a pointer to it, you can use a *compound literal* and take its address:

```
struct list *threads = &((struct list){&threads, &threads});
```

(Note: compound literals `((type){initializer})` are a C99 feature; some compilers which haven't caught up to a 13-year-old standard may reject it.)

Comment: thanks Kevin, one more question, next to struct initialization, I have something like 
void* vp_threads = threads; // if I write &threads, this's fine but without '&' its giving me error 'initializer element is not constant' Why so? any idea?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Those are two different pointers, of course. If you need help on that you should ask a separate question, and give more details on what you need to accomplish.